# Why doesn't fetchall return correct row count in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a test database and table in Python:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('embedding.db')
print("Opened database successfully")

# check whether the table exists
cursor = conn.execute('''SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{EMBEDDING}';''')
table_count = len(cursor.fetchall())

if table_count == 0:

   conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE EMBEDDING
         (ID VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
         bert           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')
   print("Table created successfully")

   conn.close()
```

I want to create the table if the table 'EMBEDDING' doesn't exist. However, the table_count returns 0 even if the table already exists. Shouldn't the count be one?

Comment: Why don't you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMBEDDING (....)`?

Comment: You are using f-string syntax `...{EMBEDDING}` but the string is not an f-string.  (In general, don't use f-strings or other string formatting syntax for values in queries, use parameter substitution)

Answer (score 0):

Use create table if not exists tablename.
And even though table exists, if there are no rows inside the table, fetchall will give you 0 results not 1